# add column based on a column value in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've this table with the following data

```
user     Date        Dist     Start
 1     2014-09-03     150       12500
 1     2014-09-04     220       null
 1     2014-09-05     100       null
 2     2014-09-03     290       18000
 2     2014-09-04     90        null
 2     2014-09-05     170       null
```

Based on the value in Start Column i need to add another column and repeat the value if not null for the same user 
The resultant table should be as below

```
 user     Date        Dist     Start            StartR
 1     2014-09-03     150       12500          12500
 1     2014-09-04     220       null           12500
 1     2014-09-05     100       null           12500
 2     2014-09-03     290       18000          18000
 2     2014-09-04     90        null           18000
 2     2014-09-05     170       null           18000
```

Can someone please help me out with this query? because i don't have any idea how can i do it

Comment: Do you really need another table or only a query?

Comment: i don't have any problem but i would like a query

Answer (score 1):

For the data you have, you can use a window function:

```
select t.*, min(t.start) over (partition by user) as StartR
from table t
```

You can readily update using the same idea:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, min(t.start) over (partition by user) as new_StartR
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set StartR = new_StartR;
```

Note:  this works for the data in the question and how you have phrased the question.  It would not work if there were multiple `Start` values for a given `user`, or if there were `NULL` values that you wanted to keep before the first non-NULL `Start` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE`/`ISNULL` and a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT [user], [Date], [Dist], [Start],
       StartR = ISNULL([Start], (SELECT MIN([Start])
                                 FROM dbo.TableName t2
                                 WHERE t.[User] = t2.[User]
                                 AND  t2.[Start] IS NOT NULL))
FROM dbo.TableName t
```

I have used `MIN([Start])` since you haven't said what should happen if there are multiple `Start` values for one user that are not `NULL`.